# Error while starting ADFv2 Azure-SSIS Integration Runtime

Tags: ssis, azure-data-factory

We are trying to start the Azure-SSIS Integration runtime in ADFv2 using the **Start-AzureRmDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntime** PowerShell command. The command runs for 20 minutes and then returns the following error: *An error occurred while requesting the status of Integration Runtime, but you can manually execute the following command: Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntime -DataFactoryName MyDataFactory -ResourceGroupName MyResourceGroup -Name MyIR –Status*. The IR is getting started, but not sure why the command shows this error. Could you let me know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an IR provisioning error, so could you show the complete error message in PSH?  Alternatively, the error message can also be found on the IR monitoring page of ADF web app.

Comment: Hi Sandy, there were no other details either in the PowerShell command or in the ADFv2 monitor page. So I tried to run the command with the -Debug option. Surprisingly, it completed without any error and the IR was started. Not sure why it would not work without the -Debug option

Answer (score 0):

I found Azure powershell version 5.1.1 has this issue, and when I upgrade Azure powershell to version 6.6, there is no such issue. you can upgrade to newest Azure powershell.